# Chad Hutchison Thomas - Developing a review site like Trustpilot

Tags: review

We are thinking to develop a simple customer review site like Trustpilot. This would be a simple site where businesses can list their business and people can review those - as simple as that.

Please suggest the best technologies / frameworks to use for this - what would be the best in long run.

Thanks,
Chad Hutchison Thomas

Answer (score -3):

you can consider NodeJS and Angular. We have recently created a similar project for a client and used these ones.

Best of luck